# Acunetix surfaces a Slow HTTP vulnerability, how do I protect against slowloris?

Tags: denial-of-service

How to protect from slowloris ?

I have installed mod_antiloris and mod_qos and acunetix still warn about slowloris.
mod_antiloris and mod_qos are loaded

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_qos/10.21 mod_antiloris/0.4

```
    `Loaded Modules:

 antiloris_module (shared)
 qos_module (shared)`
```

Comment: please be specific in what is the problem and  provide proper details

Comment: Problem is acunetix still warn me about slowloris even mod_antiloris and mod_qos are running.
How to fix it ?

Comment: Don't always trust pen-testing tools. Personally, I would attack my own server to test and see if it is working. It probably is working just Acunetix is outdated or just not working

Comment: Acunetix is updated to latest version 8.0 2013 06 26
Trying also to use AcuSensor but can't get it working
What filepath i put for file location ./filename if is in root of domain
So best is i use .pl file of slowloris ? to test it ?

php_value auto_prepend_file ‘[path to acu_phpaspect.php file]’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had success with the [mod_reqtimeout](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html) module to mitigate that Acuentix flag.

e.g.

Load the module:

```
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
```

Specify for your VirtualHost:

```
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
RequestReadTimeout header=10-20,MinRate=500 body=10,MinRate=500
</IfModule>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thx  that worked :) it also fixed "Possible virtual host found" warning with Acunetix